# font-size vs transform scale - What's the difference?

Tags: css, sass, less, transform

So, to scale font or icons, you can use: `font-size: X`.
But you can also use `transform: scale(X)`

Visually, they seem to produce the same result, but is there a difference?
Is there a reason I should try to use one over the other?

Comment: font-size only applies to text while the scale transform applies to virtually all elements

Comment: Font sizes only accept integer pixel values for example, but transform can be any arbitrary number. Transforms can be offloaded to the GPU but font sizes cannot.

Comment: [They don't produce the same result.](https://jsfiddle.net/ox7qcL2y/1/)

Comment: The important difference is that font-size impacts the containing box's size whereas transform replaces the box with an empty placeholder and resizes out of the flow.

Comment: @Sheraff that is an important difference! Thanks all, lots of good info.

Answer (score 4):

**scale** use as a percentage, and the scale goes in all directions (position: absolute), with **font-size** u can use %, px, em, rem, etc., and position will be inherit